# Bash - how to check if packages can be installed, if apt-get/dpkg is running?

Tags: apt-get, dpkg

In a bash script I want to install a package. Before sanely doing so, I need to check if no other instance of `apt-get` or `dpkg` is already working. If that was the case, the `apt-get` would fail, because its already locked.

Is it sufficient to check if `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` and `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` exists and if both don't exist, installing is safe?

Answer (score 2):

It depends how well you want to handle apt-get errors.
For your needs checking `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` and `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` is fine, but if you want to be extra cautious you could do a simulation and check the return code, like this:

```sh
if sudo apt-get --simulate install packageThatDoesntExist      
then echo "we're good"
else echo "oops, something happened"
fi
```

---

Which will give for instance:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package packageThatDoesntExist
oops, something happened
```

Edit: `--simulate` will not check for locks, so you might want to do an additional check there. You might also want to remove `sudo`, if you want to check for sudo separately.

Answer (score 2):

In Debian Wheezy (currently stable), those files always exist.  Therefore I found using `lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` to be a more useful check.  It returns 1 if nothing is using the lock, 0 if it is, so:

```
lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock >/dev/null 2>&1
[ $? = 0 ] && echo "dpkg lock in use"
```

Comment: Don't forget - this needs to be run under sudo or root account.

Answer (score 2):

Checking lock files is insufficient and unreliable. Perhaps what you really want to do is to check whether `dpkg` database is locked. I do it using the following approach:

```
## check if DPKG database is locked
dpkg -i /dev/zero 2>/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "E: dpkg database is locked."
fi
```

Hopefully there is a better way...
Besides I also do the following check as it might be unsafe to install if there are broken packages etc.:

```
apt-get check >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "E: \`apt-get check\` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting..."
fi
```

Comment: Not sure why, but lsof and fuser were both failing for me on a virtualbox guest (neither was outputting anything and both returned 1 no matter what). This solution saved me.

Comment: This is racy as it is susceptible to TOCTOU though.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check if apt-get or dpkg are running:

```
ps -C apt-get,dpkg >/dev/null && echo "installing software" || echo "all clear"
```

Comment: A potential downfall of this method is that there are many possible applications that can lock apt. As of Ubuntu 16.04 `apt` is the preferred command, which your test won't catch. Keeping up with possible front-ends could prove to be a headache.