# How find out which process is using a file in Linux?

Tags: linux

I tried to remove a file in Linux using `rm -rf file_name`, but got the error:

```
rm: file_name not removed.  Text file busy
```

How can I find out which process is using this file?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You can use the `fuser` command, which is part of the `psmisc` package, like:

```
fuser file_name
```

You will receive a list of processes using the file.

You can use different flags with it, in order to receive a more detailed output.

You can find more info in the [fuser's Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)), or in the `man` pages.

Comment: I tried this: fuser  -i /home/bin/lib. But got this:
fuser: illegal option -- i
/home/bin/lib:    27674t

Comment: @khris, might be that not all `fuser` implementations are the same, or works the same way.  Even if `-i` is defined in POSIX, the particular implementation you are using does not necessarily has the same options as the ones described in the Wikipedia article.  For example, I'm using AIX right now, and the `fuser` available in this system does not have the `-i` option either.

Comment: For some reason, neither `fuser` nor `lsof` were working for me on a virtualbox guest. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25478470/2065427) saved me.

Comment: I had to run it like `fuser -v file_name` for it to show the processes.

Comment: depending on the user that is using the file, use with sudo: sudo fuser file_name

Answer (score 47):

@jim's answer is correct -- `fuser` is what you want.

Additionally (or alternately), you can use `lsof` to get more information including the username, in case you need permission (without having to run an additional command) to kill the process.  (THough of course, if killing the process is what you want, `fuser` can do that with its `-k` option.  You can have `fuser` use other signals with the `-s` option -- check the man page for details.)

For example, with a `tail -F /etc/passwd` running in one window:

```
ghoti@pc:~$ lsof | grep passwd
tail      12470    ghoti    3r      REG  251,0     2037 51515911 /etc/passwd
```

Note that you can also use `lsof` to find out what processes are using particular sockets.  An excellent tool to have in your arsenal.

Comment: which field is the PID?

Comment: @nmz787 - `lsof | head -1` to see all the headers.

Comment: @nmz787 The second field is the PID.

Comment: `lsof | grep -E "PID|<your_process_name>"` shows both the 1st line and the process you want to query.

Answer (score 12):

For users without **fuser** :

Although we can use **lsof**, there is another way i.e., we can query the */proc* filesystem itself which lists all open files by all process.

```sh
ls -l /proc/*/fd/* | grep filename
```

Sample output below:

```
l-wx------. 1 root root  64 Aug 15 02:56 /proc/5026/fd/4 -> /var/log/filename.log
```

From the output, one can use the process id in utility like **ps** to find program name

Comment: Great answer. Bonus points for not requiring `psmisc` or `lsof` to be installed.

Comment: To filter non-existent files: `ls -l /proc/*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | grep filename`.