# How to fix 'file being used by another process' error when sending data in Postman?

Tags: postman

This is what I get after clicking Send.
**The process cannot access the file '/tmp/tmppcHPhc.tmp' because it is being used by another process.**
Please help resolve this. Thanks

I was expecting a file to get imported, but I got the above error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How find out which process is using a file in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554614/how-find-out-which-process-is-using-a-file-in-linux)